# Go through three lists simultaneously, styling output based on data in all lists

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have three lists:

```
a = {{{"I282", "I284", "S285", "D286", "T287", "P288"}}, 
     {{"N393", "S394", "V395", "I396", "E397", "K398"}}, 
     {{"K136", "A151", "A156", "G157", "A158", "K159"}}}

b = {{"A278", "G279", "S280", "G281", "I282", "I283", "I284", "S285", 
      "D286", "T287", "P288", "V289", "H290", "D291", "C292"}, 
     {"A384", "I385", "D386", "E387", "I388", "T389", "N390", "K391", 
      "V392", "N393", "S394", "V395", "I396", "E397", "K398"}, 
     {"A158", "K159", "S160", "F161", "Y162", "K163", "N164", "L165", 
      "I166", "W167", "L168", "V169", "K170", "K171", "G172"}}

c = {"AGSGIIISDTPVHDC", "AIDEITNKVNSVIEK", "AKSFYKNLIWLVKKG"}
```

If any element in each sublist in `b` is in the corresponding sublist in `a`, I need to bold the corresponding letter in `c`. All three lists' indices are associated, and their lengths are the same. The lengths of the sublists of `b` are equal to the lengths of the strings in `c`. The prefacing letters are the same.

For example, look at the first sublist of `b` which is `{"A278", "G279", "S280", "G281", "I282", "I283", "I284", "S285", "D286", "T287", "P288", "V289", "H290", "D291", "C292"}`. The output should be AGSGI**IISDTP**VHDC.

I'm struggling with this, because I'm not familiar with traversing three lists at once, and it's problematic working with the indices of letters in the strings in `c`.

I guess if you can find a way, we don't really need `c`. We could just StringTake the letters of `b`.

Comment: "traversing three lists" - `MapThread[]` is the function for situations like that. As I only have *gedanken Mathematica*, please try this yourself: `MapThread[Function[{ak, bk, ck}, Row[MapThread[If[MemberQ[ak[[1]], #1], Style[#2, Bold], #2] &, {bk, Characters[ck]}]]], {a, b, c}]`

Comment: It does the job, thank you so much @J.M.issomewhatokay. Noted about `MapThread[]`. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = StringJoin @ MapAt[ToString[Style[#, Red, Bold], StandardForm] &, #, Position @ ##2]&;
f @@@ Transpose[{StringTake[#, 1] & /@ b, b, Alternatives @@@ First /@ a}]
```

[image]

Also

```
MapThread[f, {StringTake[#, 1] & /@ b, b, Alternatives @@@ First /@ a}]
```

> same result